# Getting texts from urls is returning empty dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to get all paragraphs from a couple of websites using a for loop but I am getting an empty dataframe.
The logic of the program is

```
urls=[]
texts = []        

for r in my_list:
                try:
                    # Get text
                    url = urllib.urlopen(r)
                    content = url.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
                    # Find all of the text between paragraph tags and strip out the html
                    page = soup.find('p').getText()
                    texts.append(page)
                    urls.append(r)
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    continue

df = pd.DataFrame({"Urls" : urls, "Texts:" : texts})
```

An example of urls (my_list) might be for example: https://www.ford.com.au/performance/mustang/ , https://soperth.com.au/perths-best-fish-and-chips-46154, https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255103-zfd10901-Perth_Greater_Perth_Western_Australia-Fish_and_Chips.html, https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b07d2wy4

How can I correctly store links and the text on that specific page (so no the whole website!)?

Expected output:

```
Urls                                                       Texts

https://www.ford.com.au/performance/mustang/         Nothing else offers the unique combination of classic style and exhilarating performance quite like the Ford Mustang. Whether it’s the Fastback or Convertible, 5.0L V8 or High Performance 2.3L, the Mustang has a heritage few other cars can match.
https://soperth.com.au/perths-best-fish-and-chips-46154 
https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255103-zfd10901-Perth_Greater_Perth_Western_Australia-Fish_and_Chips.html 
https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b07d2wy4
```

where in Texts I should have for each url the paragraph containing in that page (i.e., all

elements).
It would be helpful even a dummy code (so not exactly mine) to understand where my error is. I guess my currently error might be at this step: `url = urllib.urlopen(r)` as I have no text.

Comment: Any output? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: Hi Peter. There is no output: only Urls Texts as headline and no rows. I provided the part of code that is supposed to create the dataframe with the scraped information on links and paragraphs. I added the question. It is about correctly storing links and texts. I will provide an example of expected output

Comment: If you want to find all paragraph shouldn't you use `find_all` method

Comment: Right, @BhavyaParikh. But even if I replace `find` with`find_all`, I am getting empty dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code(python3: hence the urllib.request), it works. Added user agent as urlopen was hanging up.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = []
texts = []
my_list = ["https://www.ford.com.au/performance/mustang/", "https://soperth.com.au/perths-best-fish-and-chips-46154",
           "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255103-zfd10901-Perth_Greater_Perth_Western_Australia-Fish_and_Chips.html", "https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b07d2wy4"]

for r in my_list:
    try:
        # Get text
        req = urllib.request.Request(
            r,
            data=None,
            headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
            }
        )
        url = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        content = url.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

        # Find all of the text between paragraph tags and strip out the html
        page = ''
        for para in soup.find_all('p'):
            page += para.get_text()
        print(page)
        texts.append(page)
        urls.append(r)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue

df = pd.DataFrame({"Urls": urls, "Texts:": texts})
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you @SubhashR. Do you think the problem was in urllib.request and userAgent, then?

Comment: I believe it was the user agent